# Echoing out rows in database

Tags: php, mysql

```
        <?php
         $conn= new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world"); //changed for the sake of this question

        $query = "select * from user;";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<dt>';
        foreach($row as $field) {
            echo'<dd>'.$row['FirstName'].'</dd>';
        }
        echo '</dt>';
    }
?>
```

I am just trying to echo out one column in a database atm, and it doesn't seem to display anything. I was wondering if anyone could help me?
I get this error

> [23-Aug-2012 16:14:04] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /devel/cgreenheld/projects/Asgn1final/admin.php on line 51
>   -bash-3.2$

Comment: Your `$result` is bad. Should `user` be `users` in your select statement?

Comment: I'm sure removing `;` in the query would help

Comment: @minitech: why do you think so?

Comment: Yes, the name of my database was wrong, can't believe I didn't spot that, was staring at it for ages. Haha thank you.

Comment: @zerkms: Because it works in `mysql_` and I'm sad if MySQLi doesn't support multiple queries...

Comment: @minitech: I'm sure it doesn't work in `mysql_`. And with mysqli it should trigger a error as well

Comment: @zerkms: I'm 99.9999% sure it works in `mysql_` :) But since the problem was the table name, I think courtney probably has warnings turned off and the error mode set to warnings - not a good combination :P

Comment: @minitech: oh, it does work in `mysql_` :-S

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$conn= new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$query = "select * from user";
$result = $conn->query($query);
echo '<dt>';
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<dd>'.$row['FirstName'].'</dd>';
}
echo '</dt>';
```

Comment: Point out the difference, please.

Comment: @minitech There isn't a `foreach` here, but that isn't the underlying issue.

Comment: There is no need for foreach loop (you have while)

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need ";" in your query. Second, i think you have to make sure your database connection is alive and the query returns anything.

Answer (score 0):

try connection and query ..

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Connect failed: ".mysqli_connect_error()."\n";
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `user`";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    echo '<dt>';
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo'<dd>'.$row['FirstName'].'</dd>';
    }
    echo '</dt>';
    $result->free();
} else {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
$mysqli->close();
```